# How to manually trigger refresh for Elastic search index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, indexing, opensearch

In some of the articles I found the following, to optimizing performance for bulk indexing.

> It can even make sense to temporarily turn off refreshing completely for an index (by setting the interval to -1), e.g., during a bulk indexing run, and trigger it manually at the end. [reference](https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/knn/performance-tuning/)

How do we manually trigger it? Does searching on index manually trigger it because I am able to search on the index just after it i created, didn't run any refresh api.

Answer (score 4):

In order to trigger the refresh manually, you simply need to hit the [`_refresh` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) on an index

```
POST your-index/_refresh
```

Searching on an index doesn't trigger the refresh automatically. Refreshes occur at recurring intervals, as specified by the `index.refresh_interval` index setting. If it's set to -1, then no refresh happens and you need to trigger it manually if you want fresh data.